# Java: mysql query to JList

Tags: java, mysql, jlist

My select query returns 2 columns, `ID` and `Text`
I want to display the value of Text in an Jlist which works :)

When a user clicks on the specific Jlist item, this item needs to be deleted from the database. To do this safely I need to know the ID.

How do I get to know the ID of that specific item of my JList?
Can I store this with the Jlist somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you can define the type of the elements in a `JList` just create a class that contains the id and text and then query the selected element for its id. Shouldn't be too hard.

Note that if you don't want to display the id in the list (or maybe display it in a non-standard way), you'd either have to override the element's `toString()` method or provide a custom [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).

Answer (score 0):

`JList` is an UI component following a Model-View pattern.

I suggest you to build a `ListModel` based on your query results, populate it with the information you need, and then build an `ActionListener` reacting on events on your `JList`.  This ActionListener would just read the selected index on your `JList`, and that brings you to your original object with all the information you stored on the model.